# Убрать пункт меню в AppConstants.MENU_X

Tags: android, menu, android-context-menu, sliding-menu

Скажите пожалуйста,как в данном коде можно убрать лишний пункт?

```
private void onItemClickListerner(int position, View view) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (position) {
    case AppConstants.MENU_1:
        intent = new Intent(mContext, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_2:
        doCall();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_3:
        sendEmail();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_4:
        shareClicked(getString(R.string.share_subject),
                AndroidWebsiteApplication.getAppUrl());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_5:
        intent = new Intent(mContext, ContactUsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_6:
        intent = new Intent(mContext, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_7:
        intent = new Intent(mContext, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case AppConstants.MENU_8:
        showCustomDialog(getString(R.string.confirmation),
                getString(R.string.exit_msg), getString(R.string.yes),
                getString(R.string.no), false);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    }
```

Ибо при простом удалении,приложение вылетает.Убрать пытаюсь 6й пункт.
Так записано в **AppConstant.java**

```
    // Sliding option menu
public static final int MENU_1 = 0;
public static final int MENU_2 = 1;
public static final int MENU_3 = 2;
public static final int MENU_4 = 3;
public static final int MENU_5 = 4;
public static final int MENU_6 = 5;
public static final int MENU_7 = 6;
public static final int MENU_8 = 7;
```

И так в **XML**

```
    <string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>Настройки</item>
    <item>Позвонить</item>
    <item>Письмо</item>
    <item>Поделиться</item>
    <item>Фотоальбом</item>
    <item>Карта</item>
    <item>Выход</item>
</string-array>
```

Если например убираю строчку в первом отрывке кода,то все меню сдвигается на 1 позицию и например вместо **карты** будет **выход**

Вызов

```
/**
     * Method to show toolbar and drawer layout
     */
    private void showToolbar() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
        mToolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.TitleTextStyle);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(HomeActivity.this,
                mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mNavMenuTitles = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        mNavMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
                R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mNavDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[0], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[1], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[2], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[3], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[4], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(4, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[5], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(5, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[6], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(6, -1)));
        mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(mNavMenuTitles[7], mNavMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(7, -1)));
        mNavMenuIcons.recycle();
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(HomeActivity.this);
        mMenuAdapter.setList(mNavDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            onItemClickListerner(position, view);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что за меню у вас? Добавьте код, как вы его инициализируете. Если вы пытаетесь сделать `NavigationDrawer`, то просто создайте из студии новую активити с таким шаблоном и посмотрите как там это реализовано.

Comment: @eugeneek, если правильно понял,то добавил в пост.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делать `switch` не по позиции, а по какому-то параметру самого элемента меню. Например по тайтлу:

```
switch (mNavDrawerItems.get(position).title) {  // или как у вас называется это поле 
    case mNavMenuTitles[AppConstants.MENU_1]:
        intent = new Intent(mContext, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case mNavMenuTitles[AppConstants.MENU_2]:
        doCall();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break; 
    ...
}
```

И чтобы программно удалить какой-то пункт:

```
mNavDrawerItems.remove(6);
mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChnged();
```

После этого порядок пунктов меню не должен сбиться.

Comment: Хм,так я уже пытался,идет град ошибок.Попробую разобраться,спасибо

Comment: Какие именно ошибки?